# Wizard in asp.NET MVC3 using a static object

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3, wizard

I'm trying to make a wizard in MVC3 using Entity Framework. It needs to keep the state of an object (an article in this case) across a couple of steps.
I have a static variable in my controller that instantiates a new Article. In the different Actions I use TryUpdateModel to map the form to the static variable. The problem is, it seems that TryUpdateModel() updates the database as well. I need TryUpdateModel to do the automatic mapping, and update the static _article variable, but I don't want it to persist to the database until the last step!

N.B: I know there are a lot of possible solutions for creating a wizard in MVC, but I'd like to know what to do to make this way work, so please no alternatives for an MVC wizard-pattern.

Thanks.

```
namespace website.Controllers
{
    public class ArticlesController : BaseController
    {
        // private static variable to hold the chosen article in the wizard
        private static articles _article = new articles();

    /// <summary>
    /// Index page shows a list of articles in a webgrid
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        List<articles> _articles = Data.getArticles();
        return View(_articles);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// First page of the article wizard
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public ActionResult BasicDetails(string id, string nextButton)
    {

        // back or next doesn't matter - store form values
        if (_article != null) TryUpdateModel(_article);

        if (nextButton != null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("ArticleGroup");
        }
        else
        {
            _article = Data.GetArticleById(id);
            return View(_article);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Second page of the article wizard
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public ActionResult ArticleGroup(string nextButton, string backButton)
    {
        TryUpdateModel(_article);

        if (backButton != null)
            return RedirectToAction("BasicDetails");
        else if (nextButton != null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Price");
        }
        else
        {
            return View(_article);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Third page of the article wizard
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public ActionResult Price(string nextButton, string backButton)
    {

        TryUpdateModel(_article);

        if (backButton != null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("ArticleGroup");
        }
        else if (nextButton != null)
            return RedirectToAction("LinkedClubs");
        else
        {
            return View(_article);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Last page of the article wizard
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public ActionResult LinkedClubs(string backButton)
    {

        if (backButton != null)
            return RedirectToAction("Price");
        else
            return View(_article);
    }


}
}
```

Comment: `TryUpdateModel` does not update any database. That's a MVC specific method. It doesn't even know that you are using a database. What it does is that it binds the provided model from the request parameters and applying validation logic. Now you don't want alternatives even if your current design is wrong? You use directly your domain models in the views instead of using view models. Sorry to say it but I am afraid very bumpy road is ahead of you with such design. Also static object to hold user specific state in an ASP.NET application!? WTF? What if two users fill the wizard at the same time?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you are using a static to hold the data. This is so badly wrong in a web applications I don't know where to begin. If you have multiple users (and it's a website, so you will have multiple users) they will ALL end up sharing the data in that static. They will see each others changes, overwrite each others changes, corrupt each others changes. It would be a giant mess.

Comment: Thank you guys. I am just getting started using MVC, and I was given to understand that a static private variable in a controller was a per-session container.  
Ofcourse if the pattern is broken, it's back to the drawingboard. Anyway, again, thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually data entities (entities mapped to database) and viewmodel entities (entities with that user works) used separately. When user posted data after some step - you make `TryUpdateModel()` to session object (specific for user, not for all application as static variable).
At last step you call business logic method `UpdateModel(viewmodel)`, that update all columns by id of viewmodel, using all filled properties.

Comment: Clear, so for every step in the wizard, I need to use a separate viewmodel, and in the last step I get the Entity, update it and save it to the database?

Comment: Yes, you are right. And never use static variables in controllers as containers for user-specific data :)

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using a static variable to hold your state information (that is a critical error btw) you should pass a state bag holding the information that you need in between pages.